# How to find socket port by inode struct in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a LKM program to hook `sys_read` function for reuse 80 TCP port.
But I meet an problem is that I don't know how to access Port by `inode` struct.
There is a part of my program.

```html
Linux.2.6.3.38

asmlinkage ssize_t new_read(unsigned int fd, void *buf, size_t count){
 //printk("PID %d called sys_read !\n",current->pid);
 char kbuf[MAX_BUF];
 ssize_t ret;
 struct file *file;
 ret=orig_read(fd, buf, count);
 memset(kbuf, 0,MAX_BUF);
 memcpy(kbuf, buf, ret);
 printk("kbuf:%s\n",kbuf);
 if( memcmp(kbuf, passwd, strlen(passwd)) == 0 )
 {
  file = fget(fd);
  if(file->f_dentry->d_inode->???? == PORT)  
   printk("get http message\n");
  fput(file);
 }
}
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Do sockets even have inodes?

Comment: Unix domain sockets do, but those don't have ports.

Comment: Wyzard, so no other way to get port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the `socket` structure pointer from the struct `file` with the exported function `sock_from_file`.

It is then cast into a `tcp_sock`, which contains an `inet_connection_sock` which contains an `inet_sock` which contains a `sock` (not to be confused with `socket`) which contains `sock_common`. The two port numbers are ultimately stored in `inet_sock` and `sock_common` (well, that's how it works in a recent kernel version anyway).

Making use of these facts in a reliable way would be difficult. The layout and organization of all this is closely dependent on kernel version, and of course that the file descriptor actually represents a connected TCP socket.

Comment: Hi Gil, I use `sockfd_lookup(fd,&err);` function instead of `sock_from_file` to get socket struct and I try to printk socket saddr and daddr. They are '0.0.0.0' and socket family are `AF_LOCAL` .No `AF_INET` . What's wrong?